# Why is it important to use Services for background tasks?

Tags: android, android-service

I know I should use Services in Android to do stuff in the background from a non-UI thread.

However, I would like to know what is wrong with just spawning a background thread to do the work from an Activity class (within an onClick event for example).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `Services` are used for long running tasks, especially those, that run when your activity is not running. `Threads` can be used for making some tasks inside your activity. This states, that a `Thread`, created inside your `Activity`, can not live outside of the activity that's created it, when a `Service` can. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this really helps, I want my app to send a soap request when I press a button. This will take up to 5 seconds over 3G. If I show a ProgressDialog and then make a thread to send the request, I don't need a service. Am I correct?

Comment: @Leon van Noord, Absolutely. Best solution will be using AsyncTask class here, and you surely don't need any services.